# Application wide subscription to a channel

Tags: laravel, pusher

Quick question about Pusher.js.

I've started working on a notifications functionality today and wanted to do this with Pusher.js, since I used it for my chat.

I'm working in Laravel. What I want to achieve is an application wide subscription to a channel. When a user registrates a channel is being made for him "notifications_channel", which I store in the database. I know how to register a user to a channel, but once he leaves that page, the room vacates. That's not really what I'm looking for, since I'd like to send the user notifications no matter where he is on the platform.

I couldn't really find anything like this in the documentation, so I thought maybe one of you guys know how to do so.

Here are some snippets of what I do:

When the user registrates I fire this:
`$generateChannel = User::generateNotificationsChannel($request['email']);`

This corresponds to this in my model:

```
public static function generateNotificationsChannel($email){
    $userID = User::getIdByMail($email);
    return self::where('email', $email)->update(['notifications_channel' => $userID."-".str_random(35)]);
}
```

It's fairly basic, but for now that's all I need.

So for now, when the user logs in the Index function of my HomeController is being fired, which gathers his NotificationsChannel from the database and sends it to the view.

```
public function index()
{
    $notificationsChannel = User::getUserNotificationsChannel(\Auth::user()->id);
    return view('home', compact('notificationsChannel', $notificationsChannel));
}
```

Once we get there I simply subscribe the user to that channel and bind him to any events linked to the channel:

```
var notifications = pusher.subscribe('{{$notificationsChannel}}');
channel.bind('new-notification', notifyUser);

function notifyUser(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

So as you can see, for now it's pretty basic. But my debug console shows me that the channel vacates as soon as the user leaves /home.

So the question is, how do I make him subscribed to the channel, no matter where he is on the platform?

Any and all help would be deeply appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Albert, instead of editing your question post your edition as a new reply and mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a fix to this issue, I've decided to send the notifications-channel to my Master layout, which I use to extend all views after the user has logged in. In my master layout I subscribe the user to his own notifications channel.

For people who might be interested in how I did it:

I altered the boot function of my AppServiceProvider which you can find in `\app\Providers\AppServiceProvider`. The code looks like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('layouts.app', function($view){
        $channel = User::getUserNotificationsChannel(\Auth::user()->id);
        $view->with('data', array('channel' => $channel));
    });
}
```

In my Master layout I simply subscribed the user by grabbing the channel name.